# What is the "theoretical" counterpart to "hands-on"?

Tags: phrases, writing-style

Situation: an educational event may have two parts. In the first *theoretical* part, we explain the approach, big picture, some theoretical principles. In the second *practical* part, we give the participants an opportunity to try it themselves on a few practical exercises.

There is a nice phrase **hands-on** (http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/83931?redirectedFrom=hands-on#eid2010663) with the meaning of

> Involving or offering active participation in an activity in order to gain practical experience of it; (of experience, training, etc.) practical as opposed to theoretical.

QUESTION: Is there an analogous phrase to express its *theoretical counterpart*? If I name the second part "Hands-on", what should be the name of the first part to keep the style?

ADDED: I am more up to the *same stylistic style* rather than matching *all* the nuances of *hands-on*. The main purpose is to make the  titles more attractive instead of calling it just *theoretical part* and *practical part*.

Comment: I think this is usually referred to as *practice* or *preparation*.

Comment: *Practice* or *preparation* sounds OK from the *meaning* point of view, but somehow do not sound the same stylistic style to me.

Comment: Theoretical cannot but be brains-on; unlike practical work, it cannot be delegated to others with only supervision being done for credit. As such, there's no equivalent to hands-on in the theoretical part.

Comment: @Kris brains-on was my first thought too. Why not just "theoretical?" I'm afraid you won't get a nice parallel phrase.

Comment: @Kris: I like brains-on. I admit it's not an exact parallel but for the purpose of the naming the two parts of the event it sounds pretty good to me. If you make it an answer and no one else puts here something even better within reasonable time, I'll accept it. See my recent edit.

Comment: Are you simply looking for *conceptual*? Is that all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is by no means canonical. If you want a compound that seems analogous to ***hands-on***---something that sounds kind of informal, maybe conversational, even hyphenated, why not try ***run-through***, as in:

> The first part will be a *run-through* of the fundamentals, while the second will be *hands-on*, where you can actually play around with the devices (or whatever).

Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

*Lecture,* *talk,* *lesson,* or *presentation.*

*The event involves a 1-hour lecture followed by a 2-hour hands-on practicum.*

Formal or professional term: *didactic.*

*The event will involve both a didactic and an experiential component.*

Answer (score 0):

When I was in college, many of my technical classes had a *lecture* component and a *laboratory* component. The theoretical concepts were covered in the *lecture* sessions and the hands-on training and experience occurred in the *laboratory* sessions.

Comment: -1 That's not what we mean by *hands-on* and not what the Q is about. Please see my comment at OP.

Comment: @Paul, *lecture* - *laboratory* is a nice word couple matching stylistically each other. What I am searching for is a word (or a short phrase) matching stylistically *hands-on*.

Comment: @HonzaZidek I'm having trouble coming up with a good parallel to *hands-on*. I was toying with *hands-off*, but that has a more *laisez-faire* connotation than what you're looking for. You could try *gears-on hands-off* and *gears-on hands-on* to indicate that thought should be involved either way.

Comment: @Paul, I think that your post is a good and valid comment, but not an answer. Maybe that's why 2 people gave you -1... I am willing to accept Kris's *brains-on* if he changes his comment into an answer.